# Get child inside a child in JSON / Iterate through nested JSON with jQuery/JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I wonder if this is possible, if so
how can I loop through this:

```
[
{
    "name": "Hello",
    "views": 10,
    "subMovie": [
        {
        "name": "World",
        "views": 10,
        "subMovie": [
            {
            "name": "Test 1",
            "views": 10,
            "subMovie": [
                {
                "name": "Test 2",
                "views": 10,
                "subMovie": [
                    {
                        "name": "Test 3",
                        "views": 10,
                        "subMovie": [],
                        "id": 5
                    }
                ],
                "id": 4
                }
            ],
            "id": 3
            }
        ],
        "id": 2
        }
    ],
    "id": 1
}
]
```

to get to the last child(subMovie)?

I want to access them all and print them out,
but how do I loop through this child inside a child with jQuery/JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will start with the last element of the `movies` array. After that it will descend into the `subMovie` tree by selecting the last array element of every movie it visits until there are no `subMovie`s left.

```
var movies = [
{
    "name": "Hello",
    "views": 10,
    "subMovie": [
        ...
    ],
    "id": 1
}
];

var m = movies[movies.length - 1];

while(m.subMovie.length >= 1) {
    console.log(m.name);
    m = m.subMovie[m.subMovie.length - 1];   
}

console.log(m); //Object {name: "Test 3", views: 10, subMovie: Array[0], id: 5}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a single JSON object. You have arrays contain JSON objects. if you want to learn more about JSON, check **[this article](http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp)**.

Considering your array is named `data` like bellow :

```
var data = [
{
    "name": "Hello",
    "views": 10,
    "subMovie": [
        {....
}
]
```

Using the following code :

```
data[0].subMovie[0].subMovie[0].subMovie[0].subMovie[0];
```

That will return :

```
Object {name: "Test 3", views: 10, subMovie: Array[0], id: 5}
```

Hope that help.

Comment: I know. I already tried that and it works. But what if I don't know how many subMovies inside a subMovies there will be? Lets say it can be from 0 - 100 (or even more), but I don't know how many.

Comment: Ok i'm just trying to help, take a look to the other answer it's work.

Comment: Yes, thank you for the help. I didn't explain very well at first :)