# how to get inner most child of a JSON data

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON data which is something like this, And my requirement to fetch the data of inner most children i.e **hierarchyLevel: 4**. And this JSON data is not static, the hierarchyLevel can go any thing like 5, 6, 7 any thing.
Please help to find solution in javascript.

```
{
  "hierarchylist": [
    {
      "hierarchyId": 10,
      "hierarchyLevel": 0,
      "name": "ABC",
      "parentId": 0,
      "children": [
        {
          "hierarchyId": 12,
          "hierarchyLevel": 1,
          "name": "ABC-Child1",
          "parentId": 10,
          "children": [
            {
              "hierarchyId": 2,
              "hierarchyLevel": 2,
              "name": "People Management & Development1 ",
              "parentId": 12,
              "children": [
                {
                  "hierarchyId": 5,
                  "hierarchyLevel": 3,
                  "name": "Resourcing2_1",
                  "parentId": 2,
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "hierarchyId": 19,
                      "hierarchyLevel": 4,
                      "name": "Resource Request ",
                      "parentId": 5,
                      "children": [],
                      "docId": 19,
                      "docstatusid": 20
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31776583/get-child-inside-a-child-in-json-iterate-through-nested-json-with-jquery-js

Comment: you can get by `hierarchylist.children.children.children.children`

Comment: I tried nested for loop, but as my **hierarchyLevel** is not fixed, I can not go with For loop. I am not sure I can apply the recursive function. Plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the while loop, here's the example

```
var children = json['hierarchylist']['children'][0];

while(typeof children !== 'undefined') {
    children = children['children'][0];
}

console.log(children);
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit, It helped me.

Comment: @Santosh If it helped, please accept it as answer so It can help other people.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you the inner-most one:

```js
let data = {
  "hierarchylist": [
    {
      "hierarchyId": 10,
      "hierarchyLevel": 0,
      "name": "ABC",
      "parentId": 0,
      "children": [
        {
          "hierarchyId": 12,
          "hierarchyLevel": 1,
          "name": "ABC-Child1",
          "parentId": 10,
          "children": [
            {
              "hierarchyId": 2,
              "hierarchyLevel": 2,
              "name": "People Management & Development1 ",
              "parentId": 12,
              "children": [
                {
                  "hierarchyId": 5,
                  "hierarchyLevel": 3,
                  "name": "Resourcing2_1",
                  "parentId": 2,
                  "children": [
                    {
                      "hierarchyId": 19,
                      "hierarchyLevel": 4,
                      "name": "Resource Request ",
                      "parentId": 5,
                      "children": [],
                      "docId": 19,
                      "docstatusid": 20
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

let children = data.hierarchylist[0].children;

while(children[0] && children[0].children && children[0].children.length) {
  children = children[0].children;
}

console.log(children);
```